# Is the validation set part of training set?

Tags: validation, machine-learning, model

In Machine Learning, we use validation set to tune the hyperparameters. But I am confused about the origin of the validation set. Is it part of the training set? That would mean, the model has seen the data before. Or is it like test set, i.e. data that the model has never seen before? I am really really confused..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should split training data into two parts, one for training and one for validation as you mentioned.

You train your data on the first part, while setting hyperparameters according to score on validation. Usually 80%-20% split is used, other values may be fine depending on the amount of data you have.

For final assessment of your algorithm, use another, separate, testing set, which wasn't incorporated in either training nor hyperparameters search.

Comment: I agree they should be separate. However, how come some papers at top tier venues use the val dataset for testing as well?

Comment: @dusa That's a topic for different discussion. I assume you are talking about deep learning (as that's what top tier conferences mostly are). The thing is it takes a lot of time and resources to even train those algorithms and they do require a lot of data to work (hence `test` is sometimes left out). It's sometimes also used to push SOTA and make research papers look better. All in all it depends and authors who do proper testing and are not fine-tuning by hand every possible hyperparameter should be praised for their work (though they may get less recognition because of that).

Comment: Correct in theory, however considering I want to compare my experimentation results to existing work that does not use a separate val/test split on a dataset that does not have these splits (and as I mentioned it is sort of challenging to split - it reduces the variation of the training), so I would like to know what is the consensus or what justifies that some work at top tier conferences get a pass without "proper testing".

Comment: When I submitted with my own proper splits on this dataset, reviewers were grilling me saying "oh it -probably- overfits" just because the precision was high, and standard deviation was low (average of 10 experiments). I did extreme data augmentation, created a separate val split, and did 10 fold test, but this specific paper got a pass without a separate split. Our methods are very similar too. Btw, my results were ranging between 70-90 for each category. Their basis on "probably overfits" is so random

Comment: @dusa I do feel for you, but we are making noise under simple question and simplistic answer. When it comes to DL, consensus is usually train/validation with left out test set so you can't overfit to it. But it differs for problems. When it comes to what justifies it's hard, no hard evidence but I suppose the results are never/close to never verified by reviewers. When it comes to you, reviewers were probably wrong as hardcore augmentation is nowhere near overfitting, it's the opposite. The field can sometimes be harsh and unrightfully so, that's all I can say.

Comment: Thanks for your opinion, we agree on what "must be" but my initial question addresses when it is thought to be alright because there are so many examples of this at prestigious, top tier conferences such as ICCV/CVPR. I don't know if it is as simple as not verifying results, because the authors never mention a separate val in the first place.